# cannot displaying image on emulator but when debug on browser image displaying in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to displaying image from "logo/logo.png" using

```
Image.asset(
   'logo/logo.png',
   width: 390,
   height: 220,
   fit: BoxFit.fill,
),
```

but have an error `Unable to load asset '/logo/logo.png' Exception Asset not found`
i have been added assets in pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```

and i delete space between '-' like

```
  assets:
  - assets/
```

still error and cannot displaying in emulator android but when i debug on browser the image displaying, but when i debug on android/emulator image not displatying

i expecting the app can displaying image on emulator android

Answer (score 0):

Start dir with 'assets' like so

```dart
Image.asset(
   'assets/logo/logo.png',
   width: 390,
   height: 220,
   fit: BoxFit.fill,
),
```

Comment: didn't work to me, still unable to load files

Comment: Make a directory named assets in the root directory of the project, then place the logo there. like 'assets/logo/logo.png'.